# How to load ASP.Net page data background.. & Show popup first

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

In our website, landing page taking much time to load. After loading HTML page, it is showing popup.. Because of that our customer losing patience. So please help me to come out of this..

We would like to load the popup first.. at same time we will load background page of that popup slowly..

Then we can change customer concentration from page to popup.. & we can cover delay...

For more please visit this site.. [BusETicket](http://www.buseticket.com) You can easily understand my problem..

Comment: You can use delay function in js : http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-add-3-second-delay-to-modal-pop-up-window-appearing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to crate a light-weight page which contains an empty DIV and the popup to show to customer. In addition this page should contain some javascript code which loads the entire heavy-weight page asynchroniously. Then the content of the page should be added inside DIV.
This javascript code should be invoked as soon as the popup is shown.

Answer (score 0):

call your popup on body onload. By using this your popup will be shown first.

Answer (score 0):

You have all of your JavaScript files loading in your  tag. Move what ones you can to the bottom of the page before the end  tag, the ones you don't mind loading after content.

If you feel more comfortable keeping them before content and in the same order, load the popup HTML at the top of your  tag, then include your references to your JavaScript after the HTML, then include the rest of your content. This will make your popup load first, then your JavaScript, then your site's content.

This is kind of a "hacky" way to get it done because you'll have JavaScript in the middle of your HTML, but it will get the job done. The best answer is to really evaluate why your page is loading slowly and optimize where your JavaScript is loading (put it at the bottom if you can) and what you are loading. Or, as another Egor4eg suggested, and Yahoo does this, you could always load the important content first and then asynchronously pull in other content.